# NodeJs , mongoDB : TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to **store the data** entered in HTML form into **mongoDB** but it shows error message - "TypeError: cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined"

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullname' of undefined at
>   C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\server.js:52:24 at callbacks
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
>   at param
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
>   at pass
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
>   at Router._dispatch
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
>   at Object.router [as handle]
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:33:10)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at Object.staticMiddleware [as handle]
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\static.js:55:61)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at Object.expressInit [as handle]
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\express\lib\middleware.js:30:5)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at Object.query [as handle]
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
>   at next
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:193:15)
>   at Function.app.handle
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:201:3)
>   at Server.app
>   (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\lp\node_modules\connect\lib\connect.js:65:37)
>   at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) at Server.emit (events.js:214:7) at
>   parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:634:12) at
>   HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:17)

It looks everything is correct but I don't know where i am wrong. Kindly help me to clear this error.

**server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
"use strict";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/lp", {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var engines = require("consolidate");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.engine("html", engines.mustache);
app.set("view engine", "html");
var enrollDataSchema = new Schema({
    fullname: {type: String},
    emailId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});
var EnrollData = mongoose.model("EnrollData", enrollDataSchema);
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index.html");
});
app.post("/enrollform", function (req, res) {
    var userinfo = {
        fullname: req.body.fullname,
        email: req.body.emailId,
        contact: req.body.phone
    };
    var data = new EnrollData(userinfo);
    data.save(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("thankyou.html");
        }
    });
});
app.listen(8000);
console.log("Running at Port 8000");
```

**index.html**

```
<form id="enroll" name="enroll" method="POST" action="/enrollform">
    <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" required=""/> 
    <input type="email" name="emailId" id="emailId" class="form-control" placeholder="Email ID " required=""/> 
    <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone no" type="tel">
</form>
```

**Output**

[**Here is my Output of Error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqmJq.png)

Comment: Please include erros and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: Should it be `res.body.fullname` etc instead?

Comment: Is it work ? no.  I tried it shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) module.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Glad to help! :)